# No ToolStripSeparator in ToolStrip OverflowPanel

Tags: vb.net, toolstrip

VB.NET 2013 - Framework 4.5.
When I make the size of my form with a toolstrip on it small enough, an overflowbutton appears. When clicking it I see the overflowpanel with all the buttons of the toolstrip that won't fit on it.
But the ToolStripSeparators are not shown on the OverflowPanel. Their "Overflow" property defaults to "AsNeeded", but even when I make it "Always", they do not show up. Is there a way to show them on the OverflowPanel?